# How to scrape all text from each accordion section using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium to scrape some prices off a website however the code I'm using doesn't seem to iterate through each accordion block. All I want is the Title, Item and Price of each treatment.

How to do this?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

service_obj = Service(r"C:\chromedriver.exe")
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service_obj, options=options)

url = 'https://www.23dental.com/plans-fees/dental-fees'

driver.implicitly_wait(2)
#Reject Cookies
RejectCookiesButton = driver.find_element(By.ID,"onetrust-reject-all-handler")
RejectCookiesButton.click()

#Expand all sections
ExpandAccordions = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'material-icons')
for ExpandAccordion in ExpandAccordions:
    ExpandAccordion.click()


DentalFees = []

practices = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'col-12')
for practice in practices:
    prices = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'accordion-content').text
    DentalFees.append(prices)
driver.close()

print(DentalFees)
```

Answer (score 2):

I’m going to offer a slightly different approch. I looked at the website and you don’t need to use Selenium to get this data. You don’t need to use Selenium because the data that you want is sent in the initial HTML. Here’s a good [article](https://jacobpadilla.com/articles/A-Guide-To-Web-Scraping) on what I’m talking about.

Here is some code to get what you are looking for:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

resp = requests.get('https://www.23dental.com/plans-fees/dental-fees')

tree = html.fromstring(resp.text)

for item in tree.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "pricing")]//tr'):
    product = item.xpath('./td[1]/text()')[0]
    price = item.xpath('./td[2]/text()')[0]

    print(f'{product = } {price = }')
```

Output:

```
product = 'New patient examination' price = '£75.00'
product = 'Exisitng patient examination' price = '£59.00'
product = 'Small x-ray' price = '£29.00'
product = 'Large x-ray' price = '£69.00'
product = 'Hygiene appointment 30 mins' price = '£85.00'
product = 'Extraction (simple)' price = '£119.00'
product = 'Extraction (complex)' price = '£199.00'
product = 'Simple fillings (silver)' price = 'from £109.00'
product = 'Simple fillings (white)' price = 'from £135.00'
product = 'Root canal treatment' price = 'from £269.00'
product = 'Crown' price = 'from £725.00'
product = 'Bridge (per unit)' price = 'from £679.00'
product = 'Full upper or lower denture' price = 'from £765.00'
product = 'Consultation' price = 'Free'
product = 'Implant placement' price = 'from £2,195.00'
product = 'Dental veneers' price = '£695.00'
product = 'Teeth whitening' price = '£400.00'
product = 'Band 1' price = '£23.80'
product = 'Band 2' price = '£65.20'
product = 'Band 3' price = '£282.80’
```

You may need to install requests and lxml:

```
pip install requests 
pip install lxml
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much! I had a feeling that I needed to use something else but wasn't sure where to start. Appreciate the article as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you are specific about using selenium to achieve it, here is the solution:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.23dental.com/plans-fees/dental-fees')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
# Reject All cookies
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "onetrust-reject-all-handler"))).click()

#Expand all sections
ExpandAccordions = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'material-icons')))
for ExpandAccordion in ExpandAccordions:
    ExpandAccordion.click()

all_Items = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='pricing faq pagination-item accordion-item open']")

for item in all_Items:
    title = item.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "title").text
    items = item.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "accordion-content").text
    print(title)
    print(items)
    print("------------")
```

Console result:

```
Routine treatment
New patient examination £75.00
Exisitng patient examination £59.00
Small x-ray £29.00
Large x-ray £69.00
------------
Hygienist services
Hygiene appointment 30 mins £85.00
------------
Extractions
Extraction (simple) £119.00
Extraction (complex) £199.00
------------
Repairing teeth
Simple fillings (silver) from £109.00
Simple fillings (white) from £135.00
Root canal treatment from £269.00
------------
Replacing teeth
Crown from £725.00
Bridge (per unit) from £679.00
Full upper or lower denture from £765.00
------------
Dental implants
Consultation Free
Implant placement from £2,195.00
------------
Smile styling
Dental veneers £695.00
Teeth whitening £400.00
------------
NHS
Band 1 £23.80
Band 2 £65.20
Band 3 £282.80
------------

Process finished with exit code 0
```